# How to identify zones in a table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with a table (.csv file).
The table is composed by many sub "areas" like this example:

[image: Image 1]

As you can see, there are more some data which can be grouped together (blue group, orange group, etc.)

Now.. the color is just to make the concept clear, but in the .csv there is no group identified by a color. In reality there is no color to identify the groups and the groups dimensions (rows) can change. There is no pattern to predict where the next group has 1, 2, 3, 4 or more rows.

The problem is that I need to open the table and import it using a dataframe using pandas. In my algorithm one group should be identified, copied to another dataframe and then saved.

How can I group data using pandas?

I was thinking to index the groups like the following table:

[image: Picture]

but in this case I cannot access the cells with the same index sequentially.

Any idea?

EDIT: here the table from the .csv file:

```
,X,Y,Z,mm,ff,cc
1,1,2,3,0.2,0.4,0.3
,,,,0.1,0.3,0.4
2,1,2,3,0.1,1.2,-1.2
,,,,0.12,-1.234,303.4
,,,,1.2,43.2,44.3
,,,,7.4,88.3,34.4
3,2,4,2,1.13,4.1,55.1
,,,,80.3,34.1,4.01
,,,,43.12,12.3,98.4
```

Comment: can you also post the text of the CSV? i doubt people volunteering their time to help you want to type out those values manually

Comment: You can forward-fill the values for `X`, `Y` and `Z`

Comment: @roganjosh that alone won't allow you do distinguish the orange vs blue groups

Comment: @PaulH mm, true. That's a funky index. And also one that I don't believe can exist in a CSV either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `groupby`:

```
groups = df[['X','Y','Z']].notna().all(axis=1).cumsum()

for k, d in df.groupby(groups):
    # do something with the groups
    print(f'Group {k}')
    print(d)
```

Comment: I don't follow this at all sorry. Is there some magic going on here? Isn't it just an `ffill` before `groupby`?

Comment: @roganjosh, no, because the orange cells will be assigned a group ID of 1, and the blue cells will have a group ID of 2

Comment: @roganjosh In the picture, how would you tell the orange and blue groups apart with `ffill`?

Comment: CSV format surely can't account for the screenshots now? After @PaulH corrected me, this can't exist; that's merged rows in Excel and not a CSV? Or they're all just blank entries?

Comment: Edit answers my question

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index and insert into the first position per your desired output. I have also used `ffill()` to get rid of nulls, but that is optional for you

```
# without ffill()
df.insert(0, 'index', (df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].notnull().sum(axis=1) == 3).cumsum())
# df = df.ffill() # uncomment if you want ffill()
df
Out[1]: 
   index    X    Y    Z     mm      ff      cc
0      1  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.20   0.400    0.30
1      1  NaN  NaN  NaN   0.10   0.300    0.40
2      2  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.10   1.200   -1.20
3      2  NaN  NaN  NaN   0.12  -1.234  303.40
4      2  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.20  43.200   44.30
5      3  2.0  4.0  2.0   1.13   4.100   55.10
6      3  NaN  NaN  NaN  80.30  34.100    4.01

# with ffill
df = df.ffill()
df
Out[2]: 
   index    X    Y    Z     mm      ff      cc
0      1  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.20   0.400    0.30
1      1  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.10   0.300    0.40
2      2  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.10   1.200   -1.20
3      2  1.0  2.0  3.0   0.12  -1.234  303.40
4      2  1.0  2.0  3.0   1.20  43.200   44.30
5      3  2.0  4.0  2.0   1.13   4.100   55.10
6      3  2.0  4.0  2.0  80.30  34.100    4.01
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but personally I find the solution of @Quang Hoang easier to understand.

Comment: Of course... expecially because Dave is just an abbreviation since my real name is David...